# How to use block.timestamp as it should not be deterministic

Tags: blockchain, smart-contract-wallets

I am new to blockchain and I have a question regarding variables which are not deterministic.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
contract SetCurrentTimeContract{
    uint public currentTime;

    function setCurrentTime() external{
        currentTime = block.timestamp;
    }
}
```

Suppose I have this smart contract, which sets the state variable currentTime to the current timestamp.
Now after the miner mine this, all other nodes on the chain will run the same transaction, which should result in different values.
This is situation similar to why we don't use external APIs(non deterministic) directly and use oracle instead.
Am I understanding this right?
Can anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 1):

well that's not correct actually, i think so the variable already stored the timestamp, miners when mint it they check the hash generated by contract or the abi of contract,not the what your function returns different values or calculate.